# Co.js app reports "TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: ecmascript-harmony, koa

When ever I try to run my Co.app I get

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at /home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/node_modules/thunkify/index.js:32:8
    at /home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/test.js:12:17
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
    at next (/home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/node_modules/co/index.js:70:21)
    at /home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/node_modules/co/index.js:50:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ecarroll/code/chrome-okc-plugin/test.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is the result of you thunkify-ing something that was undefined, like for instance this...

```
var readdir = thunkify(readdir);
```

when you wanted,

```
var readdir = thunkify(fs.readdir);
```

Comment: Another common case is when you forget to export the function you're calling.